# Установка Phpstrom

Tags: linux, phpstorm

Устанавливаю PHPStrom на Ubuntu 16.04. Скачал, распаковал, но при запуске sh файла пишет

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m;
>   support was removed in 8.0 Already running

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: На сколько я помню варнинги не должны были повлиять на запуск phpstorm, что-то ещё выводит в консоли?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan /opt/phpstorm/bin$ sudo sh phpstorm.sh
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
Already running

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan у себя на ноуте тоже всё было оке, а на рабочем такая беда. PhpStorm 2017-3, а java 9.0.1+11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собственно, проблемы нет никакой - все должно прекрасно запускаться, несмотря на это сообщение. Вызвано оно тем, что в вашем `.vmoptions` файле прописано свойство `-XX:MaxPermSize=350m`. Сейчас такое свойство не пишется по умолчанию, видимо, используется измененный `.vmoptions`. Вы можете проверить, что за файл используется, проанализировав [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files): открываете его в текстовом редакторе и ищете последнее вхождение строки `-Djb.vmOptionsFile`. значение этого свойства - путь к используемому файлу `.vmoptions`

Comment: теперь новая ошибка(( 
sh phpstorm.sh
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
Dec 12, 2017 7:36:24 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
INFO: Created user preferences directory.
Dec 12, 2017 7:36:24 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$6 run
WARNING: Prefs file removed in background /home/ITRANSITION.CORP/p.kushnerevich/.java/.userPrefs/prefs.xml

Answer (score 1):

Большой совет всем, кто крутит Java приложения на *nix - ставте Oracle Java. Сбережет 3-4 часа (300-400$) рабочего времени, потраченного на поиски ошибок совместимости.

https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml